# counting function for minima of continuous function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Given an absolutely continuous function  $f(x)$ with $x\in[a,b]$ and $f(x)\geq 0$ (e.g. a signal pack), I am trying to deduct analytically another function $g(x)$ which counts (similar a step function) the relative minima (or relative maxima) of $f(x)$.

Can anybody help with such a *minima counting function* or references related to such a problem?

To emphasise and avoid any confusion, it is not only about finding the minima but *counting them by an explicit function* along $x\in[a,b]$.

Many thanks in advance.